Integrating Amazon Connect with SAP S4CM Built-in CTI
SAP S/4HANA for Customer Management has built-in CTI functionality, but we're unsure how it interacts internally with other systems. Since it's a standard SAP product, we'd like to leverage its built-in CTI capabilities and avoid using third-party adapters.
Our question is:

Is it possible to directly integrate Amazon Connect with SAP S4CM's built-in CTI for functionalities like screen pop, click-to-dial, and in-call data retrieval within the Amazon Connect agent interface?

If so, what is the general process for setting up this integration? Are there any specific configuration steps or documentation available from SAP?

Alternatively, if direct integration isn't feasible, are there any known limitations of SAP S4CM's built-in CTI that would prevent this approach?


We've searched for official documentation but haven't found anything definitive regarding integrating SAP S4CM's built-in CTI with external contact center platforms.
Any insights or experiences from the community would be greatly appreciated!

Please break down the question into smaller, more specific parts.
